# How to create a flexbox with a fixed and a flex element that wraps automatically?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a flex card element that has:

- 1 fixed width element (`image-container`)
- 1 flex element (`text-container`)

I need the `text-container` element to automatically wrap when it cannot shrink any further (when it starts changing height of the container)

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="image-container">
    <h2>image here</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="text-container">
    <h2>Title text</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Dolor fuga inventore doloribus ipsam tempore? 
        Culpa temporibus ut et. Repellat. Ad natus ut illum aspernatur?
      </li>
      <li>
        Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
        Dolor fuga inventore doloribus ipsam tempore? 
        Culpa temporibus ut et. Repellat. Ad natus ut illum aspernatur?
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Here's a working Codepen example:**

**https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLXEwr?editors=1100**

- Change the window width horizontally
- See how it wraps at hardcoded `600px` after it already started stretching the container instead of doing it automatically when it cannot shrink any further.

Comment: I'm not clear on what this is supposed to look like after the "wrapping" you indicate and whether the height of the container is *ever* supposed to change.

Comment: @Paulie_D see how in the codepen the image container and the text container  wrap and become `100% width` at hardcoded value of  `600px`. I'm trying to figure out if I can do that without hardcoding the `600px` value in and let it wrap automatically before the card gets stretched vertically by the text component (look at the card height when the window width is getting closer to `600px`)

Comment: Yeah...don't think you can do that *without* a media query.